# How to change list view theme

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, themes

I was wondering how you can change the theme of a certain header under list view `<ul data-role=listview>` for example have `<h>State</h>` theme-a and right below it `<li>city1</li> <li>city2</li>` theme-b then again `<h>State2</h>` theme-a?

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <h>State</h> /theme a
    <li>City 1</li> /theme b
    <li>City 2</li> /theme b
    <h1>State 2</h1> /theme a
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list divider feature of the listview widget (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/listview/#Listdividers):

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="b">
    <li data-role="list-divider" >Mail</li>
    <li><a href="#" >Inbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Outbox</a></li>
    <li data-role="list-divider" >Contacts</li>
    <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
</ul>
```

`data-theme` affects the regular listitems while `data-divider-theme` affects the dividers.